# How would I prove that $1-\sin(x)$ is one-to-one or not?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm currently at the very beginning of my calculus course and I've run into an immediate issue in that I'm not entirely sure how to verify when a function is one-to-one. I know that they're considered one-to-one if $f(x)=f(y)$ when $y=x$, but when I apply this to $f(x)=1-\sin(x)$, the function appears as one-to-one even though I know it isn't unless the domain is restricted.

My work thus far is as follows:

Verify if $f(x)=1-\sin(x)$ is one-to-one

$f(a)=1-\sin(a)$ ;
$f(b)=1-\sin(b)$

$\Rightarrow1-\sin(a)=1-\sin(b)$

$\Rightarrow-\sin(a)=-\sin(b) \rightarrow \sin(a)=\sin(b)$

$\Rightarrow \arcsin(\sin(a))=\arcsin(\sin(b) \rightarrow a=b $

I know I'm doing something wrong, likely with the use of arcsin, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: The $\text{arcsin}$ you were using is not a function, but a relation.

Comment: Is $\arcsin(\sin x)$ always equal to $x$?

Comment: The function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $x\mapsto 1-\sin(x)$ is not one-to-one. It can be defined on different domains, and some of these will make $f$ one-to-one; the domain is very important to this question. The use of arcsin presumes we're working over an interval on which it is defined as a function.

Comment: It's the other way around: $f$ is one-to-one if $x=y$ whenever $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: $1-\sin (\frac {\pi}{6})=1-\sin (\frac {5\pi}{6})$ and yet $\frac {\pi}{6} \ne \frac {5\pi}{6}$

Comment: You are not asked to "verify **that** $f$ is one-to-one". Instead, you are asked to verify **if** $f$ is one-to-one, which means that you are asked to verify which of two possibilities is true: $f$ is one-to-one; or $f$ is *not* one-to-one. Unfortunately for you, you tried to prove that it is; but it isn't, as the answers show.

Answer (score 7):

$f$ is not one-to one:

$f(x)=f(x +2 \pi)$.

Comment: My apologies, I completely screwed up the title. I meant to ask how would I verify if it is one-to-one or not?

Comment: This answer **does** verify that the function $f(x)=1-\sin(x)$ is not one-to-one: it gives two unequal input values, namely $x$ and $x+2\pi$ (for *any* value of $x$) that have the same output value.

Answer (score 2):

Without any restriction on the domain, the function $f(x) = 1- \sin x$ is not one-to-one.

Your proof is good only when you restrict your domain for example to $(-\pi /2, \pi /2)$

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of one-to-one isn't totally correct.  A better definition is "For all x,y if f(x) = f(y) then x = y".

Simply finding an example of a case where this is true isn't enough you have to take the next step of showing that there can be no other possible case.

Answer (score 1):

From trigonometry,

$$1-\sin x=1-\sin y\iff x=y+2k\pi\lor x=\pi-y+2k\pi$$

which is not the relation we are looking for.

But if we restrict $x,y$ to the fourth and first quadrants, the term $2k\pi$ vanishes, as does $\pi-y$ (otherwise the angles would lie in other quadrants).

Then for

$$x,y\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right],x=y\iff1-\sin x=1-\sin y.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$sin(x)=sin(y)$$
gives 
$$x=\sin^{-1}(\sin y)+2n\pi,\hspace{10pt} n\in Z$$ 
$$x=(2n+1)\pi-\sin^{-1}(\sin y),\hspace{10pt} n\in Z$$ 
thus $x\ne y$

$f(x)$ is not one-to-one

Comment: $\sin \pi/4=\sin 3\pi/4$.

Comment: for disproving we just have to give an example and my  one example is enough

Comment: Indeed, my example refutes your assertion that $\sin x=\sin y$ entails $x=y+2n\pi$.

Comment: of course that it tells that I am not including every solution of sinx=siny but my one counterexample is enough to prove that it is not oneone

Comment: anyway edited the solution

Comment: Try $x=3\pi/4$, $y=\pi/4$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $f$ is one-to-one, we need to show that if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$.

Suppose we have a $g$ so that $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x$; then
$$
f(a)=f(b)\implies g(f(a))=g(f(b))\implies a=b
$$

Thus, assuming that we have an $\arcsin$ so that $\overbrace{\arcsin}^g(\overbrace{\sin}^f(x))=x$ for all $x$ assumes what is to be proven.

However, the fact that $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)$ shows that $\sin$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

In more easy and simple way to show that the function  y=1-sin(x) is not one to one  Consider that
1-sin(0)=1=1-sin(pi) while 0<>pi
that is different Abscissas gives the ordinate.